# a what is the wrong in the description function of a package

Tags: r

I want to build a package in R using R studio

I got this error when pressing on `build source package`

```
==> R CMD build CLASS_Projectcompany

* checking for file 'CLASS_Projectcompany/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* preparing 'CLASS_Projectcompany':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
Malformed package name

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
```

The content of the `DESCRIPTION` file is:

```
Package: CLASS_Projectcompany
Type: Package
Title: Class Projectcompany
Version: 1.0
Date: 2015-05-23
Author: Marco Deneenii [aut, cre]
Maintainer: Marco Deneenii <something@gmail.com>
Description: Class Project Company.
License: GPL-2
```

may you help please ?

#### Update

After i remove the `_` from the package entry, i got this error:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --build --preclean ClassProjectcompany

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing to library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library'
* installing *source* package 'ClassProjectcompany' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '��.S�': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Error : unable to load R code in package 'ClassProjectcompany'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ClassProjectcompany'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/ClassProjectcompany'

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Your original question was addressed and fixed. Now you have a completely new question. You should not edit the original post with a completely different question. If you now have a different problem, you should open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

It tells you in no uncertain terms

> Malformed package name

so I would start with the line

```
 Package: CLASS_Projectcompany
```

and actually check that underscores are permitted. They may not be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually i already started with the line `Package ...` as you see in the question. I don't know what `underscores` are, but could you tell me what should i do please?

Comment: I am starting to believe you are actually a computer program that is trying to test my patience.  What do you usually do when you encounter an English word you do not know?  Have you considered a dictionary?  Try looking up _underscore_.  Hint:  It is the symbol you typed between CLASS and Projectcompany and methinks R does not like it.  And R told you so.

Comment: thanks for your patients, i removed the `_` and I got new error message, i updated the question by that error. do you think that i need to delete the package and then re add it again with the correct name? i just feel confused because if R studio doesn't want me to have dash in the package name, why did it allow me to have it when i create the package

Comment: i hope you reply i really hope and thank you a lot a lot

Comment: Do you have this on GitHub by chance?

Comment: "I am not a computer program. you are wrong" - that sounds exactly like the kind of thing a computer program would say. And I know a bit about that myself - just ask tyler.